# Android toolbar title style

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My intentions are to use a custom view ( TextView + ImageView ) and put it as a view into a Toolbar.How can i get the style of the toolbar's default TextView for title?I'd like my TextView in my custom view to have the exactly the same outfit.I tried styling it like:

```
setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
setTextSize(18);
setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But it still looks different,are those described somewhere because i really couldn't find them.Or can i re-use the style of the title somehow?I'm getting a bit confused when it comes to styling especially from code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your coordinate layout, place this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Ezy Ride"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Now your app bar layout is ready. Customise it as you require.

In your java

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    //here set all you want!!
```

Comment: Thanks but that's a standard way i'm aware of .In my current case it has to be done programtically  and BOLD + 18 sp looks very much like the title , but still different .

Comment: For material standards, refer https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar